# How does GreenPlum handle multiple large joins and simultaneous workloads?

Tags: greenplum

Our product is extracts from our database, they can be as large as 300GB+ in file format. To achieve that we join multiple large tables (tables close to 1TB in size in some cases). We do not aggregate data period, it's pure extracts. How does GreenPlum handle these kind of large data sets (The join keys are 3+ column keys and not every table has the same keys to join with, the only common key is the first key and if data would be distributed by that there will be a lot of skew since the data itself is not balanced).

Answer (score 0):

You should use writable external tables for those types of large data extracts because it can leverage gpfdist and write data in parallel.  It will be very fast.

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/510/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

Also, your use case doesn't really indicate skew.  Skew would be either storing the data by a poor column choice like gender_code or processing skew where you filter by a column or columns where only a few segments has the data.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Greenplum Database handles this kind of load just fine. The query is executed in parallel on the segments.

Your bottleneck is likely the final export from the database - if you use SQL (or COPY), everything has to go through the master to the client. That takes time, and is slow.

As Jon pointed out, consider using an external table, and write out the data as it comes out of the query. Also avoid any kind of sort operation in your query, if possible. This is unnecessary because the data arrives unsorted in the external table file.

Comment: What I don't understand is assume you have 4 nodes and let's say to keep it simple there are 2 large tables and they are distributed not on equal keys, both tables data is split on to 4 nodes, the tables are similar in size and both are 500GB let's say, How does GreenPlum join these tables without transferring all the data to a single node or how does it do the join efficiently?

Comment: If the data is not distributed equally, you will suffer from slow performance because one or a few segments have to do most of the work. For the join in your example, the data from one table needs to be send to the other segments in order to do the joint. This happens in parallel, over the Interconnect - except when both tables have the same distribution key, then the join happens locally.